# linux mentor or hands on real world training

Tags: linux

Are there any linux mentors that provide training to people who want to learn the ins/outs of sys admin work?

Looking for something like an apprenticeship type deal.

Are local user groups of any help in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that more commonly referred to as an internship.  Depending on how much you know about various aspects (Networking, Computer Science, Previous Administration), can you probably bypass that all together and look for a position as a Jr. Administrator where they have some Sr. Linux Admins depending on your geographic location. An internship maybe be unpaid, and they might make you do tedious stuff as well, but depending on the Admin, you could still learn a lot.

Another possibility is just to reads books and find a good a community.  If you find a good community, they can answer your specific questions, or in the case of IRC you can have a dialogue about things you don't understand (I recommend irc.freenode.net).  One thing with IRC though, is people their are not always nice, so you just kind of have to ignore that and just be grateful for the information they are giving you.

I have heard good things about Local groups that you mentioned (LUGs), so that might be a good place to start as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is get some books on the subject.  There are also training programs available for preparing for various certifications but these tend to be pricey.

You can also see if there's a [LUG (Linux User Group)](http://www.linux.org/groups/) in your area.  You may find someone who is willing to help you out from time to time there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a couple of decent books on sysadmin stuff, install VirtualBox or VMWare Player on your PC, download whatever you find that runs in a VM and have at it.

If you need a more structured approach to learning, you can use various certification outlines (such as RHCE or Linux+) as a good overall reference of what to focus on.

Comment: problem with a VM is that it isn't live, so you can really test serving web pages on a domain etc., but good point.  there are enough virtual hosts out there for $20/month to test on that allow for rollbacks and snapshots etc.

Comment: What's not live about a VM? Of course you can test serving web pages on a domain, but it's up to you to configure the domain & relevant networking to allow you to do so. You don't need a $20 VPS for this.